# Splitting of degenerate energy levels with a perturbed particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, perturbation-theory

Suppose you have a particle in a square box $[0,L]\times[0,L]$. As the box is a square, the (2,1) and (1,2) eigenfunctions will have the same energy. If you were to apply an oscillating electric field in the $x$-direction so that the Hamiltonian would become 
$$
H \psi=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta \psi -e\,\vec{x}\cdot \vec{E}(t)\psi
$$

(where, again, the field is in the $x$-direction--say $\vec{E}(t) = (A cos(\omega t),0)$ ), the second energy level would split in two.

I'd like to know what the two lowest energy levels of the perturbed Hamiltonian are, and, more importantly, whether the second energy level corresponds to (2,1) or (1,2).

Comment: Why don't you apply perturbation theory? You know how to solve for the Eigen values and functions for $E = 0$. Just perturb the equation to the number of terms you need.

Comment: In fact, as the Hamiltonian is time-dependent, there are no energy levels per se, because energy is not conserved there. So I'm really sure which energy levels you mean to compute.